# c++ - How to create commands with variables to be executed in cmd

Tags: c++

Let me specify the question. I want to make commands so when user will type eg. `go (something)` it will use the `go` to specify the function and `something` to find what the program should do when variable equals `something`. If there is anything unclear, just ask, i know my explanation is strange.

Example:

In program there is a `void go(string choice)` function with `if` condition including few variables that can be used through `choice` string.

User is opening program and typing `go` and then string. Program goes to function `go` and if string is included in `if` loop, then program goes to specific if condition and does what it should eg.:

```
if(choice == "room")
{ 
//condition being executed
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please rephrase, or add an example.

Comment: I'm a little unsure of what you are asking. Are you asking how to run specific functions using the command line?

Ie: `myprogram.exe go string`
Which will call go function with the string?

Comment: Not specifically. When he runs program, I want the user to be able to run the `if` condition in go function by typing something like `go` and string which will match `if`.

Comment: Instead of telling us what you want to do, tell us where you are struggling and show us some code you've produced to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want a specific function to be executed according to a cmd line input? Easy! Create you main function like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

argc is the argument count and argv is the argument value. Google up on this if you need more info, it's widely used. Use an if statement inside your main function that will call the required function according to the value of argv[]. So when you execute your program you'll execute like

```
exe_file_name go anything
```

If you want to call multiple functions dynamically during a single execution you could instead do
getline(cin,choice);

```
if(strcmp(choice, "room")) //condition
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be like

```
if(strcmp(choice , "room")){//condition being executed}
```